# Typescript reports error "property does not exist on type" when I move type validation code to an external function

Tags: typescript, interface, abstract-syntax-tree, control-flow

I have a function that checks whether an object is of a certain type. If it is not, then I want to throw an error (I'm doing all this in tests).

The interesting thing is that when I move my error-throwing type validation code into an external function, I get Typescript errors, but if I leave it with the other code, Typescript gets it and doesn't complain about properties not existing (i.e. `Property 'vehicle' does not exist on type 'SomeParentType'`).

In other words, this works:

```
function appendToOutputString(obj: SomeParentType) {
  if (!isChildTypeA(obj)) {
    throw new Error("Must be of type ChildA!");
  }
  outputString += obj.vehicle;
}
```

but this **does not** work

```
function appendToOutputString(obj: SomeParentType) {
  expectIsChildTypeA(obj)
  outputString += obj.vehicle;
}
```

---

Here is a link to my full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/checking-type-in-function?file=index.ts

And here is a paste of it:

```
interface SomeParentType {
  title: string;
}

interface SomeChildTypeA extends SomeParentType {
  vehicle: string;
}

interface SomeChildTypeB extends SomeParentType {
  animal: string;
}

let outputString = "";

function isChildTypeA(childType: SomeParentType): childType is SomeChildTypeA {
  return "vehicle" in childType;
}

function expectIsChildTypeA(obj: any) {
  if (!isChildTypeA(obj)) {
    throw new Error("Must be of type ChildA!");
  }
}

function appendToOutputString(obj: SomeParentType) {
  // if (!isChildTypeA(obj)) {
  //   throw new Error("Must be of type ChildA!");
  // }
  expectIsChildTypeA(obj)
  outputString += obj.vehicle;  // Typescript complains!!
}

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("app");
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>${outputString}</h1>`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can sometimes recognize that a variable is of a type narrower than its annotated or inferred type at certain points in the code, by [analyzing the control flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis).  In the following code block, the compiler understands that `obj` must be a `SomeChildTypeA` if the flow of control reaches the `outputString += obj.vehicle` call, and thus there is no error:

```
if (!isChildTypeA(obj)) {
  throw new Error("Must be of type ChildA!");
}
outputString += obj.vehicle;  // okay
```

---

As you've discovered, though, simply refactoring the code to make the check happen in a different function does not work.  The compiler generally does not follow control flow into functions and methods when performing control flow analysis.  This is a [tradeoff (see Microsoft/TypeScript#9998 in GitHub for more info)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998): it's not feasible for the compiler to simulate the program running on all possible inputs, by analyzing the possible control flow paths through all possible function calls, so it has to use a heuristic somewhere; in this case, the heuristic is generally "assume function calls have no impact on variable types".  Therefore the call to `expectIsChildTypeA(obj)` has no impact on the type of `obj` as seen by the compiler, and thus it complains about `obj.vehicle`.

---

Luckily, [TypeScript 3.7 introduced "assertion functions"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions); you can give a function a special *return type* that tells the compiler that a variable passed to the function will be narrowed by the function, and it will use this as part of its control flow analysis.  While the compiler doesn't infer such function signatures itself, at least now you can manually annotate that `defined()` asserts something about its argument:

```
function expectIsChildTypeA(obj: any): asserts obj is SomeChildTypeA {
  if (!isChildTypeA(obj)) {
    throw new Error("Must be of type ChildA!");
  }
}
```

The return type of `expectIsChildTypeA()` is `asserts obj is SomeChildTypeA`, which means that `obj` will be verified as `SomeChildTypeA` if the function returns.  And this fixes your original example:

```
expectIsChildTypeA(obj)
outputString += obj.vehicle;  // okay
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAKcoTgAqAngA4oDeAsAFDLJjBgA2EAXMgM5hSgDmAbjoBfOnVCRYiFBmwBhABbAWAE1IUAgsggAPSCFVc0WXPkJgNVOgwBuEZQjacefEENHjak6PCQmFZTUrACEdfUIjALMCYnJremQ4EGBMOBYXXgFhWjFaOjYwZHQAVzAyMtQs92QAXmQAIgacuhgSkAQmdBBkYC4lFXV4zQAKBCChik45GIsrAEpOccGrXuMZgeDh5BpEgjASqB6G+0c2Bt6e5a2KHLzW9s7gbvCKToBJfomrUfQAIwAVpxkiRFkkuFxoGBjP8AWtoptJhBtLsGMAYMgRgBCPqIn4jWHzeY7GwMRiKKDoADuyBAEBpAFEoJSoCMGgBZEo8ZB-FDoDFgeLIRGaLENeY5Bh5e60NodLo9OBkCiGIjoADyZQqYCqbn4BMB01MeFilnixNRrwgHy+K2GBoB81JpXKlWq-GQAGp6rCAHSnYBOCCCBgAelDxQA1nASJ58rRw8gAOp8SDIKyoBB8MhFBDoVQQLF0PMgblKsgAEWAtk4AAkiOyADIMtjYcB1ZCqdAIEptsC+-gQMAtiB9kIkd6qNnl8VYnLlqu2X2gOlQetNjsAAwAPIoAIwAPgAJJQXdrdQIRNvQ-uD5vBEA)